# How to create session and time out with node js for whatsapp cloud api webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, whatsapp

I have project for create bot whatsapp using cloud API. For that I'm using nodeJS express webhook, and I want to save that session with phone number and interval time out like 30 minutes. Everytime the message comes to my webhook, if idle or not get interaction of person, will be reset sessions or delete that phone number on the session I save. In my code I can't save phone number which comes. What should I do?

```
const session = {};

function sessionMiddleware(sessionTimeout) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    const phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    const sessionId = req.body.sessionId || getSessionIdFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    if (sessionId && sessions[sessionId]) {
      const session = sessions[sessionId];
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      if (currentTime - session.lastAccessTime > sessionTimeout) {
        // Session has timed out, remove the session
        delete sessions[sessionId];
        req.session = null;
      } else {
        // Session exists and is valid, update the session data and reset the timer
        session.lastAccessTime = currentTime;
        session.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        req.session = session.data;
      }
    } else {
      // Session does not exist or is invalid, create a new session
      const newSessionId = generateSessionId();
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      const newSession = {
        sessionId: newSessionId,
        creationTime: currentTime,
        lastAccessTime: currentTime,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        data: {}
      };
      sessions[newSessionId] = newSession;
      req.session = newSession.data;
    }
    next();
  }
}


function getSessionIdFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  // Get the session ID for the given phone number, if it exists
  const sessionIds = Object.keys(sessions);
  for (let i = 0; i < sessionIds.length; i++) {
    const sessionId = sessionIds[i];
    const session = sessions[sessionId];
    if (session.phoneNumber === phoneNumber) {
      return sessionId;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function generateSessionId() {
  // Generate a random session ID using the uuid package
  const uuid = require('uuid');
  return uuid.v4();
}

app.post("/webhook",sessionMiddleware(30 * 60 * 1000), (req, res) => {
  // Parse the request body from the POST
 

  // info on WhatsApp text message payload: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/payload-examples#text-messages
  
      let phone_number_id =
        req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.metadata.phone_number_id;
      let from = req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].from; // extract the phone number from the webhook payload
});
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem with your code? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: i want to make bot chat in whatsapp with if idle  or not get interaction of person in 10 minutes, will be reset sessions or delete that phone number on the session i save.  in my code i cant save phone number wich come.